# How do you convert jpeg (uint8) to tiff (float32) format in Python for raster band indices?

Tags: python, numpy, rasterio

I need to develop an initial python code to take 8-bit unsigned integer JPEG images that have RGB bands, run a VARI band index: (Vari = (green - red) / (green + red - blue)), and then provide the output image with values ranging from -1 to 1.

I have tried utilizing GDAL and running the process through a struct.pack method to calculate the index value for each pixel line by line but I think that was making this to complex.

Currently I have a code written using Rasterio, but I cant find a way to get the values to return correctly due to the formatting issue. 
- The input JPEG being 8-bit uint means that the resulting values are on a scale from 0-255
- If I try to divide by max value the format rounds to 0 for every pixel value within the image
- When I try to define the output as float32 I get an error about JPEG formating or str formatting depending on the code used

```
    import rasterio
    import numpy
    image_file = "input file name"

    # We handle the connections with "with"
    with rasterio.open(image_file) as src:
    band_red = src.read(1)

    with rasterio.open(image_file) as src:
        band_green = src.read(2)

    with rasterio.open(image_file) as src:
        band_blue = src.read(3)

    # Allow division by zero
    numpy.seterr(divide='ignore', invalid='ignore')

    # Calculate VARI
    vari = (band_green.astype(rasterio.uint8) - 
    band_red.astype(rasterio.uint8))/ (band_green + band_red - 
    band_blue.astype(rasterio.uint8))
    vari_out = vari

    # Set spatial characteristics of the output object to mirror the input
    kwargs = src.meta
    kwargs.update(
        dtype=rasterio.uint8,
        count = 1)

    # Create the file
    with rasterio.open('output file name', 'w', **kwargs) as dst:
        dst.write_band(1, vari_out.astype(rasterio.uint8))
```

The VARI band index should return values for each pixel ranging from -1 to 1. At this point I am almost positive the formatting differences between input and output are the problem, but I am having trouble finding a way to get around this. If you have any suggestions or if I am doing this entirely wrong, please let me know what you think will work.

Comment: I have problem to understand what the problem is. In python3 vari is float array.

Comment: Why have you removed all the `import` statements?

Comment: I can't help thinking you need to move from `np.uint8` to `np.float` far sooner in your calculations - in fact as soon as you do `green - red` the result could be negative and not fit in `np.uint8`...

Comment: @MarkSetchell I added my imports, and I agree with you about moving to float prior to the calculation. My follow up for you is how to best accomplish that move?

Comment: Make the conversion with `floatArray = intArray.astype(np.float32)`

Comment: @MarkSetchell Please excuse my beginner questions, I sincerely appreciate your insight, but I've been on a 3 year hiatus from coding. I've added    floatArray = intArray.astype(np.float32)    and changed "intArray to my image file name, and still wind up with "'str' object has no attribute 'astype'"